# How can I batch convert flac files to wav?

Tags: portable, music-management, transcode, digital-audio

I'm using Windows XP, and I have several (about 160) flac files which I need to convert to wav. Since it is not practical to convert so many one by one, I need a utility that can convert them, <del>but also preserve the metadata. It is crucial that the metadata is present and not altered,</del> and I would highly prefer anything portable (sans-installation), and command line utilities would help too.

Thank you for helping

==EDIT==
I don't need the metadata, can this conversion be done now, somehow?

Comment: Uhm, WAV has very limited metadata support you know?  It simply can't handle everything that can be stored in a flac file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default flac distribution include a binary called `flac(.exe)`. You can decompress flac files with it using the -d option.

Just use the cmd shell from the folder with .flac files:

```
FOR %f IN (*.flac) DO "C:\Program Files (x86)\FLAC\flac.exe" -d "%f"
```

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I needed. It also has an option to write to STDout (EXACTLY what I needed), so this is perfect.

Comment: I have encountered difficulties when feeding the output from flac into lame. The duration of the mp3 files comes out wrong sometimes. It's possible to recalculate the length of VBR mp3s using some utility (e.g foobar2000), but I find it generally safer to use intermediate wav files.

Answer (score 0):

[MediaMonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com) can do both the conversion and metadata mapping. It can also be installed in portable mode.

Answer (score 0):

The solution above did not work for me on Windows 7 (I got errors about the FOR syntax).

I needed to recursively convert a ton of flac files in place, so I did the following.

1. Create a batch file called **decompress_flac.bat** with this in it:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /R %1 %%G IN (*.flac) DO (
    ECHO "Attempting to convert %%G"
    flac.exe -d "%%G"
)
```

2. Open up a command prompt and cd to wherever you put the batch file, if it isn't in your PATH.
3. Call the batch file:

```
decompress_flac.bat f:\
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really easy to do in [Reaper](https://www.reaper.fm/download.php) (freely available uncrippled shareware DAW) if you don't feel like going into the command line.

Just drag all your flac files into Reaper. Then select File - Render - Stems - WAV - set filename wildcard to $track - and hit go.

It's detailed here: https://www.doctormix.com/blog/how-to-export-multiple-tracks-in-reaper

Answer (score 0):

In macOS I used brew to install the flac binary and then ran this which will go through the current directory and feed flac files to decompress.

find . -name "*.flac" -exec flac -d {} \;

Comment: Does this answer the question how to convert flac files in Windows XP?